# How to generate the NIC configuration file of VM in VMware workstation after I add a NIC?

Tags: vmware, network-adapter

I close the VM(CentOS 7.2) in the VMware workstation, and then add a new network interface adapter (VMnet6, you can see in the below snapshot).

[image]

But if I start the VM, and cd to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`, there still have two NIC configuration files, how to generate the file automatically?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

if I use the `ip a`, I can the the newer network interface.

Comment: VMware isn’t concerned with what the guest OS does. So this isn’t a VMware or even VM question, but instead a CentOS question.

Comment: I use the VMware workstation to add the NIC.

Comment: Yeah, so? It’s no different from, say, connecting a USB network adapter to a “real” PC.